# Sending HTML with Mutt (or another terminal mail client)

Tags: command-line, mutt, mime-types, html, email

While I can find some scattered info on the topic, I can't seem to find a straight walkthrough (or even a definite answer)...

Basically I'm too low on the totem pole to start sending plain-text e-mails. My company requires an HTML signature that includes the logo image.

The problem is I'm fed up with GUI mail clients. Is it possible to configure Mutt in a way that would allow me to have all messages I write injected to an HTML template (with an embedded image)? Or will I just have to deal with Thunderbird's chaos?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *huge* hack, but somebody has already done the [work for you](https://dgl.cx/2009/03/html-mail-with-mutt-using-markdown).

**Edit:** What if you attached your signature as an HTML file?

`mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" someone@somewhere.com -s "Hello" < mysig.html`

Comment: Ah, yes I've seen this link. I was hoping to find a better answer floating around before I went ahead with all that...